# How to unravel data interpolated with griddata

Tags: python, scipy

I have interpolate a function on a grid with `scipy.interpolate.griddata` like so

```
 interpolated_quantity = scipy.interpolate.griddata(old_points, old_array, grid_x, grid_y, grid_z, method='nearest')
```

What I would like to do is to convert have a set of 4 1-D arrays: 3 with the position of each cell and one with the corresponding value of `interpolated quantity` in each cell.

So far I'm using a very slow and time consuming operation:

```
arrays={}

base_gridx = linspace(xmin,xmax,abs(ngridx)+1)
base_gridy = linspace(ymin,ymax,abs(ngridy)+1)
base_gridz = linspace(zmin,zmax,abs(ngridz)+1)
cx = (base_gridx[1:]+base_gridx[:-1])/2.
cy = (base_gridy[1:]+base_gridy[:-1])/2.
cz = (base_gridz[1:]+base_gridz[:-1])/2.

data_len = len(cx)*len(cy)*len(cz)

for ii in arange(0,len(cx)):
  for jj in arange(0,len(cy)):
     for kk in arange(0,len(cz)):
       arrays["x"].append(cx[ii])
       arrays["y"].append(cy[jj])
       arrays["z"].append(cz[kk])
       arrays["prop"].append(interpolated quantity[ii][jj][kk])
```

This works, but it just takes a huge amount of time. Do you think there might be a faster way to do this? Maybe using `ravel`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is as simple as you suggest. The four arrays are:

```
grid_x.ravel()
grid_y.ravel()
grid_z.ravel()
interpolated_quantity.ravel()
```